# How to make Wpf scrollviewer adjust according to Image scaling?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, scrollviewer

I have create a Wpf user control which shows user image and also allows user to zoom in or out of the image using the mouse scroll.I am using scrollviewer control to allow scrolling in case image size is larger than its container. Scrollviewer works fine when the image size is larger than its container. But when the image size smaller than it container the scrolls do not disappear. So, how do I make the scrolls disappear if the image can fit inside the container. Below is the xaml I am using:

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <!--<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">-->
            <Image  x:Name="PdfImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseWheel="PdfImage_MouseWheel" ClipToBounds="True">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
            <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
        </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the code that I am using to allow user to zoom in or out image:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
{
                    var st = (ScaleTransform)PdfImage.RenderTransform;
                    double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
                    double newXScaleValue = st.ScaleX + zoom;
                    double newYScaleValue = st.ScaleY + zoom;
                    if ((newXScaleValue >= 0.1 && newXScaleValue <= 4) && (newYScaleValue >= 0.1 && newYScaleValue <= 4))
                    {
                        st.ScaleX += zoom;
                        st.ScaleY += zoom;
                    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `PdfImage_MouseWheel` code as well? Why do you include inner scrollviewer (and grid)?

Comment: @Sinatr I have added the code. And I tried to add scrollviewer directly over Image and over its parent grid, both of them did not work.

Comment: Do your scrollbar dissapear when the image (at it initial size) fits the ScrollViewer?

Comment: @KacperStachowski No, the initial size of image is greater than the container. Hence, scrollbars are there from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying a render transform. This kind of transform is applied after the measure and arrange steps and is independent of the layout. From the scroll viewer perspective, the content width and height never change, no matter how much you zoom in or out. Try using Image.LayoutTranform instead.